# Web Browser Navigation Failed

Tags: vb.net, browser, web

I've tried searching this with no solution yet but is there any way I can find out if there has been an error while trying to load the page.

```
For example:
404 page not found
Navigation failed
```

And any other types of failed navigation that doesn't bring the website up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would link you to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227334(v=vs.60).aspx

for writing a 404 tracker in VB